# not displaying the same tags ? in php

Tags: php, tags, grouping

Not sure this is an architecture question or not, please fix if i am wrong,
ok i have a arrays ( by using a foreach )

```
foreach ($db['products'] as $product) 
{
    echo '<li><a href="">' . $product['tag'] . '</a></li>';
}

 // displays like
 tag1
 tag4
 tag2
 tag2
 tag1
 tag3
 tag1
 tag1
 tag3
 tag2
 tag3
 tag2
```

do anyone have an idea how to show

```
//count tags & no duplicate tags ?
tag1(4)
tag2(4)
tag3(3)
```

like stackoverflow have ?

edit one ( PDO )

```
$database->fetchall("SELECT pid, uid, name, information, image_tumb, tag, price 
FROM products ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 100");
```

edit two when i do this

```
$db['products'] = $database->fetchall("SELECT pid, uid, name, information, image_tumb, tag, price 
FROM products GROUP BY tag ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 100");
```

it does work, but some products are not displaying.

- all product is displayed
- but the tags are just like above.

thanks for your time btw, its save my learning time alot.

edit* it work. thanks all

```
$db['products'] = $database->fetchall("SELECT pid, uid, name, information, image_tumb, price 
FROM products ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 100");

$db['tags'] = $database->fetchall("SELECT tag, COUNT(tag) AS counter
FROM products GROUP BY tag ORDER BY tag DESC LIMIT 100");


        foreach ($db['tags'] as $tag) {
            echo '<li><a href="">' . $tag['tag'] . '(' . $tag['counter'] . ')</a></li>';
        }
```

buy doing this i still get all of my products with a list of tags no duplicate + counter. thanks again!.

Comment: This could easily be achieved by changing your DB query. Can you show that section of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an array to remember the items that already have been displayed:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {
    if (!isset($items[$product['tag']]) {
        $items = 1;
    } else {
        $items++;
    }
}
foreach ($items as $tag => $count) {
    echo '<li><a href="">' . $product['tag'] . ' (' . $count . ')</a></li>';
}
```

Or you sort the array in advance and just compare the current item with the previous one:

```
array_multisort($db['products'], array_map(function($item) { return $item['tag']; }, $db['products']));
$previous = null;
foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {
    if ($product['tag'] !== $previous['tag']) {
        if ($previous !== null) {
            echo '<li><a href="">' . $product['tag'] . ' (' . $counter . ')</a></li>';
        }
        $counter = 0;
    } else {
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

But you can probably do the same within your database query and just grab the results like:

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(tag) AS counter
FROM table
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY tag
```

Answer (score 1):

What query do you use to pull out the data from SQL? Probably we can do it from SQL level?

something like

```
Select tag, count(tag) from products group by tag;
```

Comment: doing it but it seems that my product is not displaying all, its due to the group by tag. want i want to learn is to make my products ( display all ) but making tags joined if same, somehow. you can see it from above. ive made an edit.

Comment: You don't have the `count(tag)` on your query, can you try?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably modify your query to return the data in two columns, `tag` and `count`. Without seeing your query, I can't tell you how to do this.

You could also change the organization of your tags without modifying the query:

```
// Build a tag => count mapping
$tags = arrya();
foreach ($db['products'] as $product) 
{
    if (array_key_exists($product['tag'], $tags))
      $tags[$product['tag']] += 1;
    else
      $tags[$product['tag']] = 1;
}

// Display the tags with their counts
foreach ($tags as $tag => $count) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"\">$tag($count)</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$productCounts = array();

foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {
    if (empty(productCounts[$product])) {
        $productCounts[$product['tag']] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $productCounts[$product['tag']]++;
    }
}

foreach ($productCounts as $product=>$count) {
     echo '<li><a href="">' . $product . '(' . $count . ')</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't such extra codes, you use [array_count_values](http://bd.php.net/array_count_values) function. Here is an example -

```
<?php

$a = array("tag1", "tag4", "tag2", "tag2", "tag1", "tag3", 
            "tag1", "tag1", "tag3", "tag2", "tag3", "tag2");
$b = array_count_values($a);
print_r($b);
```

?>